# JSCH Channel doesnt disconnect after command execution

Tags: java, ssh, server, terminal, jsch

I have to put a timeout 6 before my request to the server otherwise it gets stuck in the while loop. I lose valuable seconds there because 6 is an arbitrary number of seconds and Im doing around 200 request to the server through JSCH.

I executed the request `nc 127.0.0.1 8008 <<< '(47.6861,-70.3343) (48.2191,-68.9323) 100000'` in the terminal (connected through ssh) and it seemed to stand by after I got the return value so I have to CTRL-C to return to cancel that command.

One option that comes to my mind is to do the request with another command other than `nc` but I cant find another. thanks

```
public String doRequest(String request) throws JSchException, InterruptedException {
        channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        String responseString;
        channel.setCommand("nc 127.0.0.1 8008 <<< " + "'" + request + "'");
        //channel.setCommand("timeout 6 nc 127.0.0.1 8008 <<< " + "'" + request + "'");
        ByteArrayOutputStream responseStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        channel.setOutputStream(responseStream);
        channel.connect();
  
        while (channel.isConnected()) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        responseString = responseStream.toString();
        return responseString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: add the option -q to nc cat:

`channel.setCommand("nc -q 1 127.0.0.1 8008 <<< " + request);`.

It will end the connection after 1 seconds once it reaches EOF. So my request  takes 4 seconds it will properly close after 4 + 1 second after. if its 10 seconds, its going to be 10 + 1. and so on.